# Sublime Text continue current CTRL+D selection

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

This one is hard for me to explain, I'm sorry, but I have pictures!

When I hit ctrl+d twice, it selects the first two `foo`, like this:

[image]

Then I can change those, and all the other `foo` are still highlighted:

[image]

But if I hit ctrl+d again now, it selects both `bar` because that's where my cursors are. I'm trying to change two `foo`s at a time, as efficiently as possible. How can I get the next two selected? They're still highlighted so I think there has to be a way?

Comment: So, your scenario is that they're all called `foo` and you want to pairwise set them to different new stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

One, use <kbd>F3</kbd> to "Find next" which will highlight the third foo. So, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> now will have the next two foo's selected. (<kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>G</kbd> instead of <kbd>F3</kbd> for Mac users)

Option two:

Do it manually with the arrow keys, reselecting as you go.

Comment: `Find next` isn't `ctrl+g` on windows, it's `F3`, but that's exactly what I was looking for! arrow keys don't always work if instead of `bar` I'm renaming it to something really really long

Comment: Ah, I was just guessing :) It usually is ctrl instead of cmd. And the arrow keys work if you also manually reselect. It's what I do if I misclick something for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply. When u make changes to those first foo, your cursor stays at the end of first foo. Just press arrow-key down, so the cursor goes to second-line foo, than ctrl+d again -> changes -> arrow-key down -> ctrl+d and on and on..

**ADDED:**

When edited text goes longer, than second line's 'foo', you can always navigate to the line begining. Maybe Home button? 
If home is not a solution, you can always make your own keybindings, maybe, this way:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+left"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+right"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
```

This way you will be able to get to lines begining by pressing Ctrl+alt+left.. of course u can change it - code is pretty simple.

Comment: If instead of `bar` I renamed it to something really long this wouldn't work

Comment: Edited a bit. Maybe home button or custom keybinds?